# Many-to-many relationship with a one column ‘junction’ table?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, sql-server-2016

Basically trying to get my head around how to enforce primary / foreign key constraints on what is essentially a many-to-many (M:N) relationship. Or if I should ignore them in this instance...

The schema design below is based on the following.

- Shops sell fruit (item)
- The fruit for each shop can be retrieved from certain warehouses that have stockcodes
- Multiple shops have access to multiple warehouse
- Multiple warehouses supply multiple shops

---

---

```
--Fruit Stock levels (PK surrogate key, item and stockcode unique constraint)
DECLARE @stock TABLE(item VARCHAR(50),stockAmount INT,stockCode VARCHAR(5))
INSERT INTO @stock( item, stockAmount, stockCode )
VALUES   ( 'apples',  10, 'SC01' )
        ,( 'bananas', 15, 'SC01' )
        ,( 'apples',  10, 'SC02' )
        ,( 'oranges', 50, NULL ) --no stock code as 50 avaibale from any warehouse 

--Stock allocated into stockpiles/warehouses. Each warehouse has a code e.g SC01 Shops have access to certain warehouses. Table keys currently (Composite key on code & shop, can change this?)

DECLARE @stockForShop TABLE(code VARCHAR(5),shop VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @stockForShop( code, shop )
VALUES   ( 'SC01', 'shop1')
        ,( 'SC01', 'shop2')
        ,( 'SC01', 'shop3')
        ,( 'SC02', 'shop9')
        ,( 'SC03', 'shop1')

--1 column ‘junction’ table to enforce primary and foreign key constraints
DECLARE @stock_stockForShop TABLE (code VARCHAR(5))
INSERT INTO @stock_stockForShop(code)
VALUES ('SC01'), ('SC02'), ('SC03')

--SELECT  * FROM @stock
--SELECT  * FROM @stockForShop

--Query to get shops and what stockpile the products can sell to via  from
--using ‘junction’ table (enforce primary key on actual tables)
SELECT * FROM @stock s 
LEFT JOIN @stock_stockForShop ssfs ON s.stockCode = ssfs.code
LEFT JOIN @stockForShop sfs ON ssfs.code = sfs.code

--no ‘junction’ table
SELECT * FROM @stock s 
LEFT JOIN @stockForShop sfs ON s.stockCode = sfs.code
```

Comment: What PRIMARY KEY / UNIQUE constraints do the tables have?

Comment: Surrogate key in stock with unique constraints.. Composite key in stockForShop

Comment: Can one shop access multiple "stock piles" (`stockCode`)? or is that relationship one-to-one?

Comment: Also - do stock piles have attributes of their own (such that having them in a table has potential value, for identifying them based on those attributes)? For example, would a stockCode be tied to a particular date, a particular point of origin, or have a human-understandable label of some sort?

Comment: @RDFozz yes a shop has access to multiple stock piles for fruit..have shown this in the table now. A stockpile could be seen as a warehouse..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would include the table you're calling `@stock_stockForShop` (though I might change the name to something like `@stockpile` or even `@warehouse` if that actually makes sense in context.

A `stockCode` represents a unique entity in your schema; it defines a set of inventory that is available to a set of stores. If you do not store it and enforce it as a foreign key, you have to allow new codes to be created via `@stock` and `@stockForShop`, meaning that a typo could create a `stockCode` that is not used anywhere else, leaving the associated stock to potentially go to waste. This is, perhaps, the most important point - ensuring that all `stockCode`s are well established and usable, and that new ones are only created deliberately.

In addition, a `stockCode` might also have important attributes that you might want to be able to search on from an application: it could be tied to a specific geographic location (such that it would make sense to connect to shops within 100 miles of it, but no farther), or contact info (phone/fax/email).

So, I would have the `@stock_stockForShop` table, and would make IDs referring to other tables as foreign keys (again, making sure that typos don't create virtual new `stockCode`s).

Terminology note: I would consider `@stockForShop` to be your linking/mapping table (which is how I read "junction"), as it ties a shop to one or more warehouses, and a warehouse to one or more shops.

Comment: I'm with you on everything except... how can `@stockForShop` be the mapping table? That would mean columns `code` and `shop` would be FKs but `stockCode` is not unique in the `@stock` table therefore can not be a primary key. Hence the introduction of the table `@stock_stockForShop`  which can contain the primary key `code` which will be a FK to `stockCode` in `@stock` table and FK to `code` in `@stockForShop` table

Comment: `@stockForShop` is the table that actually establishes the many to many relationship, presumably without other attributes being attached. As I noted, there might very well be logical attributes to be attached to `@stock_stockForShop`, but `@stockForShop` just lets a shop use multiple warehouses, and a warehouse be connected to multiple shops. Note that it may simply be a matter of perspective, and if I understand the entirety of your system I might see it the same way you do.

Comment: @davey `code` is unique in `@stock_stockForShop`. It seems you use different terminology than most. `@stock_stockForShop` does not look like a junction table. The other 2 tables are!

Comment: Actually I suppose you're right, in a way it is the junction table. A junction table between stockCodes and shops. The `@stock` table has a FK to `@stock_stockForShop` as is unrelated to the junction table